# Redux-Saga watcher action being invoked twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I have my saga setup in the following manner.

```
export function* watchInstanceDataSetAssocSaga() {
  yield takeLatest(
    actionTypes.FETCH_INSTANCE_DATASETS_ASSOC_INITIATE,
    fetchInstanceDataSetAssocSaga
  )
}

const actionWatchers = sagaMiddleware => {
  sagaMiddleware.run(watchInstanceDataSetAssocSaga)
}


function* fetchInstanceDataSetAssocSaga(action) {
  console.log('in saga')
 //Making Api Call
}

const composeEnhancers =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
    ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose
    : null || compose
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware))
)
actionWatchers(sagaMiddleware)
```

In my container component, I am dispatching the action to invoke the saga.

```
export class InstanceDatasetsAssoc extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    console.log('in componentWillMount')
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    if (!this.props.records.length) {
      console.log('in did mount')
      const {
        pageInfo: {
          first: { url }
        }
      } = this.props
      let paginationParams = {
        url
      }
      this.props.onFetchInstanceDataSetAssoc(paginationParams)
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

I get the following log statements when I hit url.

**

```
  in componentWillMount
  in saga
  in did mount
  in saga
```

**

My saga gets invoked twice as I get "in saga" twice so my api call happens twice.

Can someone explain what is it that I am missing??

Comment: I don't see an error in the code you shared. I even tried it in codesandbox and the log is fine https://codesandbox.io/s/xp8v0mvjvq . The error is somewhere else, I would check with redux-logger that you are not dispatching the action accidentally somewhere else.

Comment: You are right..i was populating the react-bootstrap table via remote flag for server side pagination. I had written code in the he handler provided by the library which was dispatching an action on page load too!!
Thanks for taking the effort to check. Your comment helped me in actually starting off with a clean slate again.